# Timeout en la ejecucion de este codigo en Javascript. La idea es buscar en el arrary los numeros que sean iguales

Tags: javascript, nodejs

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function(inputStdin) {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.split('\n');

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}


function countingSort(arr) {
    // Write your code here


let arrayfinal = [];
const k = arr.length;
 let mayorQueDiez = [];
 
for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
    arrayfinal.push(0);
}



arr.map(el => {


    let mayorQueDiez = arr.filter(element => element === el);

    arrayfinal[el] = mayorQueDiez.length
})
    return arrayfinal;
}

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const n = parseInt(readLine().trim(), 10);

    const arr = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(arrTemp => parseInt(arrTemp, 10));

    const result = countingSort(arr);

    ws.write(result.join(' ') + '\n');

    ws.end();
}
```

La idea es contar los numero que sean iguales en el array y colocarlos en otro array en la posicion del numero encontrado. Por ejemplo.

arr=[1,5,6,7,7,6,10,22,23,23,25]
Con el nro 1 hay solo 1, el numero 5 tiene 1, el nro 6 esta 2 veces....
cuando me dan un array de 1 millon de nros... me da un Timeout.

Que seria mas optimo usar como iterador?
ya use forEach,use map, use filter.. y da Timeout.-

Comment: hay 3 iteraciones ahi.. porque 3?

Comment: no entendi tu pregunta

Comment: Aca tienen datos para probar el codigo: [enlace](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/226657/input03.txt?response-content-type=text%2Fplain&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV%2F20231115%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231115T183633Z&X-Amz-Expires=7200&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=4714a1e0f5f4862bf0de8770df9597d00524594363ee01d74687888a8b324575)

Comment: Claro.. decis que tarda mucho.. pero primero, generas en una iteracion un array con todos ceros... luego haces un map (que recorre todo el array, y aplica la funcion a cada elemento) y dentro de esa funcion, haces un filter que vuelve a recorrer todo el array, por cada una de las iteraciones de map, buscando elementos que cumplan la condicion... o sea, si el array tiene 100 elementos, recorres 100 veces los 100 elementos... estas iterando demasiado...

Comment: es mas.. te diria, que sobran hasta iteraciones.. cuando encontras el segundo 7, ya en realidad contaste que habia dos 7... porque lo hizo el filter, sin embargo, vos volves a contar la cantidad de 7 que hay... podrias evitarlo comprobando si ya existe en el resultado comprobando si es mayor que 0... pero para mi, tenes que replantear la funcion...

Answer (score 0):

Considereaciones:

- Estas realizando 2 iteraciones, una para llenar con ceros (innecesaria) y otra para contar las ocurrencias.
- La forma más eficiente para añadir un objeto a un array es a través de su índices, es decir esto `array[indice]=valor` es más eficiente que `array.push(valor)`. Lo cual solo sirve para caso donde el largo del array es previamente conocido (como tu caso)
- Para crear un array dimensionado se hace `let array = Array(dimension)`, lo cual retorna un array de largo `dimension`, donde cada elemento es `undefined`
- Una iteración `for` con indice (el for de toda la vida) `(let index = 0; index < 100; index++)` es más rápido que un iteración sobre iteradores
- Puedes medir el tiempo de un algoritmo usando `performance.now()`

Aquí un derivado de tu código, generando un array de número aleatoreo de largo `10.000`, que para mi caso retorna alrededor de `680 milisegundos`

```js
const Rand = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;

function CreateFakeArray(num){
  const array = Array(num);
  for(let i=0;i<=num;i++){
    array[i] = Rand(0,100);
  }
  return array;
}

function countingSort(arr) {
  const t0 = performance.now();
  let arrayfinal = [];
  const k = arr.length;
  let mayorQueDiez = [];
 
   for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
    arrayfinal.push(0);
   }

   arr.map(el => {
     let mayorQueDiez = arr.filter(element => element === el);
     arrayfinal[el] = mayorQueDiez.length
    });
    const t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(`${t1 - t0} ms.`);
    return arrayfinal;
}

const result = countingSort(CreateFakeArray(10000));
```

Aquí un código usando todas las consideraciones antes mencionadas y con array de largo un millón

```js
const Rand = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;

function CreateFakeArray(num){
  const array = Array(num);
  for(let i=0;i<=num;i++){
    array[i] = Rand(0,num);
  }
  return array;
}


function countingSort(arr) {
  const t0 = performance.now();
  let arrayfinal = Array(arr.length).fill(0);
  for(let i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
    arrayfinal[arr[i]]++
  }
    const t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(`${t1 - t0} ms.`);
    return arrayfinal;
}

const result = countingSort(CreateFakeArray(1000000));
```

Comment: con un millon no te da timeout?

Comment: Gracias Yussef amigo !!!!

Comment: @msalga El código con las mejoras y un array de un millon, demora en mi PC 17ms

Comment: ```    function countingSort(arr) {

        const countArray = Array(100).fill(0);
    

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            countArray[arr[i]]++;
        }
    

        return countArray;
    }
    

   const arr = [1, 1, 3, 2, 1];
    const result = countingSort(arr);
    console.log(result);
```      Me anduvo asi..

Comment: @msalga no entiendo ese código que pusiste :S

Comment: @msalga Creo que ya entendí lo que me querías decir, hice el cambio correspondiente en mi respuesta

Comment: ese codigo resuelve ese problema del timeout. esa funcion primero llena el array de ceros como pide la consigna, y luego en cada posicion el nro del array que hace de indice del arraynuevo donde ira acumulando los totales. Use el for tradicional como me dijiste. Gracias Yussef maestro!

Answer (score 0):

```
   function countingSort(arr) {

        const countArray = Array(100).fill(0);
    

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            countArray[arr[i]]++;
        }
    

        return countArray;
    }
    

   const arr = [1, 1, 3, 2, 1];
    const result = countingSort(arr);
    console.log(result);
      Me anduvo asi..
```